# How to create a method inside class without this keyword for returning components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint

Consider the below given code:

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import Deck from './src/Deck';
import Item from './src/Item';

class App extends React.Component {
  renderCard( item ) {
    return (
      <Item key={ item.id } imageUrl={ item.uri } />
    );
  }

  renderNoMoreCards() {
    return (
      <Card title="All Done!">
        <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
          There's no more content here!
        </Text>
        <Button
          backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
          title="Get more!"
        />
      </Card>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Deck
          data={DATA}
          renderCard={this.renderCard}
          renderNoMoreCards={this.renderNoMoreCards}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
});

Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
```

I have enabled ESLint for JavaScript code linting and I get an error `Expected this to be used by class method renderNoMoreCards(). (class-methods-use-this)`.

I know what the error means but then how can I create methods to return `jsx`? I can create this method as a static method, but how do we pass static methods as props?

Comment: Where does `styles` come from?

Comment: Yep. I'll modify code to reflect that.

Comment: Why not trying the bind, `renderNoMoreCards={this.renderNoMoreCards.bind(this)}` or arrow function `renderNoMoreCards={() => this.renderNoMoreCards()}` ? You should do this.

Comment: @Aruna The problem is with the method being used without "this". That's when ESLint throws error and not with passing it as props. Also, I wanted to  know how to pass "static" methods as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can create this method as a static method, but how do we pass static methods as props?

By referring to them, they're properties on the constructor. So if the containing class is `App`, it'd be `renderNoMoreCards={App.renderNoMoreCards}`:

```
static renderNoMoreCards() {
  // ...
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />
      <Deck
        renderNoMoreCards={App.renderNoMoreCards}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Another option is a standalone function (presumably this is in a module, so it would be private to that module):

```
const renderNoMoreCards = _ => 
  <Card title="All Done!">
    <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
      There's no more content here!
    </Text>
    <Button
      backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
      title="Get more!"
    />
  </Card>
;

class App extends React.Component {
  renderCard( item ) {
    return (
      <Item key={ item.id } imageUrl={ item.uri } />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Deck
          data={DATA}
          renderCard={this.renderCard}
          renderNoMoreCards={renderNoMoreCards}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```